# How to conditionally redirect to the post from a taxonomy page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I would like to redirect to a post if the taxonomy term it belongs to has only one post assigned to it and so far I have this:

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = 'product_range';
$term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    if($term->count <= 1 ) {
      echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($child, $taxonomy_name) .'" class="thumb" title="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    }
}
```

This links through to the archive page but I want it to redirect the user to the relevant post, I am not sure what I need to do to change the permalink to go to the single post page.

Comment: Do you want to be **redirected** to the post from the category or do you want to output the link of this post in the category which would hardly make sense to me since your category should already include the post...?

Comment: I want to link through to the post from the taxonomy.

Comment: Does it mean you don't want your user landing on the category page if it has only one post? In this case, it's called a redirection.

Comment: Yes I don't want the user to land on the Category page, I need them to be redirected to the post if only 1 post exists.

Comment: OK then, see my updated answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ClemC I managed to figure this out by adding a WP_Query to query the posts and check the count, here is my code:

```
    $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        $taxonomy_name = 'product_range';
        $custom_terms = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
            echo '<div class="row row__condensed">';
            foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
                $term = get_term_by( 'id', $custom_term, $taxonomy_name );
                wp_reset_query();
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_range',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                 );

                $loop = new WP_Query($args);

                if($loop->have_posts()) {

                    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                        // If only one post exists link to product
                        if($term->count === 1 ) {
                            echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
                                echo '<div class="grid__item">';
                                    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';                                                       
                                    echo '</a>';
                                    echo '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">'.$term->name .'</a></h3>';
                                    echo '<p>'.wp_trim_words($term->description, 23, '...').'</p>';
                                echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                        //else link to the listing page
                        else {
                            echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
                                echo '<div class="grid__item">';
                                    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $custom_term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">';                                    
                                    echo '</a>';
                                    echo '<h3><a href="' . get_term_link( $custom_term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">'.$term->name .'</a></h3>';
                                echo '<p>'.wp_trim_words($term->description, 23, '...').'</p>';
                                echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    endwhile;
                }
            else {
        echo "no posts found.";
            } //endforeach
        echo '</div>';
```

Comment: It was probably not working because of the missing `'post_type' => 'product'` arg in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/)'s `$count` property which should hold the number of posts attached to this current term.
Then, **if** only one post is attached to this term, query this post object and do your stuff with it...

```
$term = get_queried_object();

if ( $term->count === 1 ) {
    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'         => 'product_range',
                'field'            => 'term_id',
                'terms'            => array( $term->term_id ),
                'include_children' => false,
            ),
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $posts = $query->posts;
    $post  = $posts[0];

    /**
     * IMPORTANT FOR SEO...
     * Temporary redirection until your category is populated - Use 301 instead of 302 to redirect permanently...
     */
    if ( wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->ID ), 302 ) ) {
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't redirect me to the post.

Comment: @NeelamKhan, I updated my answer to change `'terms' => $term->term_id` to `'terms' => array( $term->term_id )`. Let me know if it works or not...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it, I appreciate your help though. I am trying to get it to work.

Comment: @NeelamKhan what is the output of `var_dump( $term );` and `var_dump( $posts );` ?

Comment: the output of `var_dump($post);` is array(0) { } and the output of `var_dump($term);` is all the taxonomy information.

Comment: `object(WP_Term)#6203 (12) {
  ["term_id"]=&gt;
  int(53)
  ["name"]=&gt;
  string(4) "25mm"
  ["slug"]=&gt;
  string(4) "25mm"
  ["term_group"]=&gt;
  int(0)
  ["term_taxonomy_id"]=&gt;
  int(53)
  ["taxonomy"]=&gt;
  string(13) "product_range"
  ["description"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["parent"]=&gt;
  int(49)
  ["count"]=&gt;
  int(4)
  ["filter"]=&gt;
  string(3) "raw"
  ["menu_order"]=&gt;
  string(1) "0"
  ["term_order"]=&gt;
  string(1) "0"
}
`

Comment: @NeelamKhan... Let's try with `WP_Query` instead of `get_posts()`... See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @ClemC I managed to get it working with WP_Query. Not quite what you suggested above but I managed to get it working.

Comment: @NeelamKhan, glad it helped you out, but could you be more precise about what you had to change from my code? Thanks.